# Enable Return Key when Pasting into a UISearchController's UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

I'm running into a similar problem to the one described in a [bug report](https://openradar.appspot.com/22774460) to Apple.

Basically, when pasting text into a `UISearchBar` (part of `UISearchController`), the **Return key** is not enabled on the keyboard. (It gets enabled when typing characters though).

Essentially, `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` is ignored, as this property should be `true` by default.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Let `UISearchBar` of a `UISearchController` become first responder.
- Paste text into `UISearchBar`
- Press `Search` button on keyboard

**Expected Results:**

- Search button is enabled.

**Actual Results:**

- Search button stays disabled.

## Question

Even though this seems to be a bug, is there a workaround for this particular problem ? Especially that some apps like Twitter or Product Hunt got around it somehow.

Comment: I filed the linked bug report back in 2015, forgot about it, then went searching SO this morning to see if anyone else had a similar problem :)

Answer (score 4):

The following will do it. Note that if pasting into a search bar that already has text, the search button will already be enabled, so a special-case is only needed when the current search text is empty.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text.characters.count > 0 && range.length == 0 && range.location == 0 {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It really does the trick regarding enabling the return key, but it would be awesome if it could also preserve the keyboard state (for example if the user toggled capitalization or numbers mode). Right now if I toggle the number mode and then paste something ... the `resignFirstResponder()` apparently loses the keyboard previous state